# How to replace single quotes that appear when using split() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, toml

I have a string, `list1` that I'm converting to a list in order to compare it with another list, `list2`, to find common elements.

The following code works, but I need to replace `'` with `"` in the final output, since it will be used in TOML front matter.

```
list1 = "a b c"
list1 = list1.split(" ")

print list1
>>> ['a','b','c']

list2 = ["b"]

print list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
>>> ['b']

**I need ["b"]**
```

New to python. I've tried using replace() and searched around, but can't find a way to do so. Thanks in advance.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: `"b"` and `'b'` are equal in python. Both single quotes and double quotes give strings.

Comment: @modesitt. Thanks. The final output will be used in TOML front matter that's why I need it to be "b".

Comment: whatever library you are using to write to TOML will surely supply options for quote types when saving

Comment: ok. but is it possible to replace the quotes even though they are equal?

Comment: the only reason you see them in the REPL as `''` is because that is how python `repr`esents strings.

Comment: There's nothing *to* replace. Neither `"b"` nor `'b'` contain any quotes. If you need TOML output, use a TOML library rather than expecting `str.__repr__` to produce proper TOML values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other structured text format, use a proper library to generate TOML values. For example

```
>>> import toml
>>> list1 = "a b c"
>>> list1 = list1.split(" ")
>>> list2 = ["b"]
>>> v = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
>>> print(v)
['b']
>>> print(toml.dumps({"values": v}))
values = [ "b",]
```

Answer (score 0):

made it

```
import json
l1 = "a b c"
l1 = l1.split(" ")

print(l1)


l2 = ["b"]

print(json.dumps(list(set(l1).intersection(l2))))

print(type(l1))
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
["b"]
<type 'list'>
```